# How do I troubleshoot an old two-cycle engine that stalls after idling for 20 seconds?

Tags: fuel-system

I have a craftsman trimmer that I've not used in years.  I'm using semi-old fuel mixture so I definitely know that may be contributing but I think this happened when I was using it prior to this.

Here is a video I recorded of the problem.
Please any input is greatly appreciated!

http://youtu.be/yWNnHRqjFF4

Comment: can you jockey the throttle button to keep it running?

Comment: Probably a better fit for gardening.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Steven - i agree

Comment: I don't think its a fit at gardening, either.  It would have been a fit at small engine repair, but it died a lingering death in Area 51

Comment: Gas filter or partial line blockage? Do you have to wait a while before it'll start up again? Throttle seems to work, so trimmer's apparently OK, when it can get the fuel it wants. Might be a very dirty air filter choking it for air, but that usually prevents starting at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must drain the old fuel mix before doing anything, it can make a world of difference. Old fuel leaves nasty deposits that mess up the carb operation. You'd be well served to clean out the entire fuel system with carb cleaner and replacing all filters. Replace the spark plug while you're at it.

With hopefully a clean system and new plug, and certainly fresh fuel mix and clean filters, try it again, it may work fine. If not, you may just need a minor carb adjustment. You typically need to locate the slow idle mixture screw. I'm not familiar with this engine, so the procedure may vary. Check the owner's manual, they should have a section on idle adjustment. One typically adjusts the idle screw so the engine runs fast enough to not stall, but not so fast the head turns.